# Vue test utils: '[object Object]' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to get an element by its `ref` attribute from the wrapper, but it is throwing an error shown below.

According to the [documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/selectors.html#find-option-object), my usage of `find` seems to be correct.

```
 SyntaxError: '[object Object]' is not a valid selector

  13 |     const lis = wrapper.findAll('li');
  14 | 
> 15 |     const a = wrapper.find({ ref: 'first' });
     |                       ^
  16 | 
  17 |     console.log(a);
  18 | 

  at emit (node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:565:17)
  at _querySelectorAll (node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:1513:9)
  at Object._querySelector [as first] (node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:1424:14)      at VueWrapper.find (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.cjs.js:192      at Object.it (tests/unit/example.spec.js:15:23)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usage of `find` is deprecated according to the [current `find` docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#find):

> **Deprecation warning**
>
> Using `find` to search for a Component is deprecated and will be removed. Use `findComponent` instead.

And it looks like that support is completely removed now. `find` currently only accepts a selector string.

To find a component by `ref` name, use [`findComponent`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#findcomponent) instead:

```js
wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'first' })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your ref value by `this.$refs.first`

Comment: Inside the component yes, but here is inside the file '.spec.js', I'm testing the component with jest, it is different

Answer (score 0):

Support for `find` is removed in Vue Test Utils 1 (for **Vue2**): [vue2_find_docs](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#find).

Vue Test Utils 2 (for **Vue3**) specifies that `find` should be used for HTML elements while `findComponent` should be used for Vue components: [vue3_find_docs](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#find).

Make sure that you are referencing the correct documentation for your Vue version and that you have the correct vue-test-utils package installed.